# Randomly select index positions in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
data  = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
    [3,3,3,4,7,7,7,8,11,12,11],  
    [3,3,3,5,7,7,7,9,11,11,11],
    [3,4,3,6,7,7,7,10,11,17,11],
    [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]])
required = np.where(data==11)
print required

(array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([ 8, 10,  8,  9, 10,  8, 10,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int64))
```

From the **required** how can I randomly select (with out re-occurring) only 3 index positions?

**The answers should be index positions as a subset of required.**

my trial:

```
result = np.random.choice(required, 3, replace=False)
print result

ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

any idea to solve this problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do the job:

```
import numpy as np
data  = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
     [3,3,3,4,7,7,7,8,11,12,11],  
     [3,3,3,5,7,7,7,9,11,11,11],
     [3,4,3,6,7,7,7,10,11,17,11],
     [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]])
required = np.where(data==11)

coords = zip(required[0], required[1]) #Create pairs of indices as tuples
for i in np.random.choice(len(coords), 3, replace=False): #Pick random index values for coords
    print coords[i] #May want to do something other than printing here.
```

Comment: `len(coords)` is the length (number of elements) of the coords list. Assume `len(coords)` is 5. I'm passing it to `np.random.choice` as an integer without replacement. So, now it has to pick numbers from [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]. Let's say after 3 picks, the result is [0, 3, 1]. Then I pass these values to the coords list as indices for coords itself, which, in return, holds the filtered x and y indices for your 2D array called `data`. [EDIT: more elaboration]